# Cassandra select query ERROR: No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators:

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql

I executed the query like this in razor sql.

```
SELECT * FROM number_log where phonenumber = '6032969081' and is_active='1' ALLOW FILTERING
```

Its giving me an error like -

> ERROR: No secondary indexes on the restricted columns  support the
>   provided operators:  'SELECT * FROM  number_log
>   where phonenumber =  '6032969081' and is_active='1' ALLOW FILTERING'

can anyone please help me out -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cassandra, select via a non primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793438/cassandra-select-via-a-non-primary-key)

Comment: Though secondary indexes are available, it comes with huge performance penalty for the query which you are trying to run. You should model your data according to your query requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add an index on your column....

```
CREATE INDEX ON <b>table_name</b> (<b>field_name</b>);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out....It can help you about your issue.
http://tonylixu.blogspot.in/2015/04/cassandra-no-secondary-indexes-on.html

Comment: Can we get rid off using indexes as it slows down the fetching process?